# how do I use functions from separate files in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on some server-side javascript and I have some data that I want to keep sensitive, so it's in a non-public facing directory. Let's say I put it inside a function - how do I then call that function from within another javascript file?

Comment: Why would your server side JavaScript be in a public facing directory in the first place?

Comment: The documentation for loading scripts from files in node.js can be found at http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Comment: Thanks very much - I've found out the answer from that documentation and have answered my post.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Quentin for pointing me towards the relevant documentation. The solution I ended up with is:

sensitive.js:

```
exports.data = "data";
```

app.js:

```
var sensitive = require('./sensitive');
var data = sensitive.data;
```

Comment: Don't add sensitive data to your codebase. Pull it in from the environment instead by putting the sensitive module in your home directory. http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

Comment: I'm using heroku to deploy this app, and am unsure of how to access the home directory. My deployment is just done by pushing the whole app directory to the heroku server. I'll look into it though, as others must have come across this problem.

Comment: On Heroku you can specify custom values using environment variables, then pick those up from a configuration module in your app. Usually sensitive data is in the form of crypto keys, passwords, etc so that's a reasonable place to put that from a logistical perspective.